# How to install emacs modules when using snap emacs

Tags: apt, dpkg, snap, emacs

After upgrading to 19.10, the upgrader removed my emacs dpkg installation (a bit rude but at least I accepted it) and now the terminal recommends installing it from snap. I did, but I can't find how to install the extra modules that I need. For example the `yaml-mode` module, this was called `elpa-yaml-mode` in dpkg

Is it even possible to access all these emacs modules that were available in apt now in snap? I want to give a try to the official recommended way before I go back to dpkg

Answer (score 3):

Snaps are isolated, so you can't change their internals. Remove it with

```
snap remove emacs
```

I would recommend to install Emacs and the module as regular deb-packages

```
sudo apt-get install elpa-yaml-mode
```

and use them in convenient way.